# Applying owlcarousal not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

Hi I am applying the owl carousal to element but it is not applied but also $(this).data('owlCarousel) is also present.why is it not applied,I am using version  2.0 of owl carousal.

[image][image]

Comment: Where's your code...?

Comment: $("#"+"dhillon"+self.categoryId).owlCarousel({
//options come here
})

Comment: $("#abc").owlCarousel({
                    pagination: false,
                    center: false,
                    nav: true,
                    mouseDrag: false,
                    loop: true,
                    margin: 0,
                    dots: false,
                    slideBy: 1,
                    autoplay: false,
                    autoplayTimeout: 2500,
                    autoplayHoverPause: true,
                    autoplaySpeed: 800,
                    startPosition: 0,
                    }
              });

Comment: Add your HTML and JS for this so we can answer your question as to why it is not working.

Comment: I have added the images.

Comment: So all your 'items' are `<article>` elements and your parent container holding items is `<div id="{{'dhillon'+categoryId}}">` .. I'd start by verifying that there are no errors on the page and that your selector `self.categoryId` matches the output in the markup. I'm not sure if your selector is correct.

Comment: no problem with selector at all.it is applied for first time but when click on tab again html populates again but carousal not

Comment: Means first time carousal populates fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I managed to solve the problem

```
var $carousel = $(".related-product");
                $('.related-product').data('owlCarousel').destroy();
                $carousel.removeClass('owl-carousel owl-loaded');
                $carousel.find('.owl-stage').children().unwrap();
                $(".owl-item.active:first-child", $(".owl-stage-
                  outer")).each(function(indx,element){
                   $(this).parent().remove()
```